# How to load JavaScript CSS files in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, partial-views

I have a partial view page, I want to load JavaScript And CSS files in this partial view.

Please help me how do I do this?

I want to load these three files in Partial View

```
<link href="~/AdminTheme/BootstrapJalaliDatePicker/css/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/AdminTheme/BootstrapJalaliDatePicker/js/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/AdminTheme/BootstrapJalaliDatePicker/js/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.fa.min.js"></script>
```

Partial View:

```
<div class="col-md-12">               
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StartDate" class="control-label">
                StartDate
            </label>
            <input id="sdDate" class="Date form-control" name="stDate"/>    
            <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
             
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EndDate" class="control-label"> 
                EndDate
            </label>
            <input id="edDate" class="Date form-control" name="edDate"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>                  
    $(document).ready(function() {       
        $('.Date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", isRTL: true, 
            showButtonPanel: true });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Just add it to the partial view. You can add JS and CSS blocks everywhere throughout the HTML, not just in the header.

Comment: And what happens when you add them to your partial view?  What's not working that made you ask this question?

Comment: I want the date plugin to be displayed,

Comment: This partial view performs operations in Ajax. After refreshing the page, the date plugin is displayed, but after a record insertion operation, the date plugin is no longer displayed to insert a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution obtained:

```
   $(document).on("focusin",".Date", function () {
         $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", 
            isRTL: true, 
            showButtonPanel: true
           });
        });
```

add css:

```
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
```